# Text always moving behind slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having an issue with some text that I want to put in a container below a slider always appearing behind the slider. I've tried different options in CSS but I can't seem to get the text moving.

Here is the example of the project: [Example](http://atwebdesign.be/a3l/frontpageLS/)

Below you can find the html/css on jsfiddle

The text should appear in the div A3L_slogan. I've tried using margins, but that doesn't make it responsive am I right?
To say it in short. The text should appear below the carousel in the center of the page.

Hope anyone can point me in the right direction or help me out

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
  zoom: 1;
}

header {
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.container {
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo-box {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.logo-box a {
  outline: none;
  display: block;
}
.logo-box img {display: block;}
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  float: right;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 25px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  transition: .5s linear;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #868686;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav a:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 15px;
  background: #868686;
  transition: width .5s linear;
}
nav a:hover:after {width: 100%;}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  header {text-align: center;}
  .logo-box {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  }
  ul {float: none;}
  nav li:first-of-type {margin-left: 0;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
nav {overflow: visible;}
nav li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
nav li:hover {background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);}
nav a:after {content: none;}
}

#slide {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:600px;
}
.slide1 {
  background: url(http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-159465.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
.slide2 {
  background: url(http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-160434.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
.slide3 {
  background: url(http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-150988.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
    $('.fadein div:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
      $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('div').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');
    }, 3500);
  });
    </script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo-box">
          <a href="/">
            <img src="images/logo.png">
          </a>
        </div>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Forums</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Rules</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Monetization</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Sign-up</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Staff</a></li>
           </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="fadein">
       <div id="slide"class="slide1"></div>
       <div id="slide"class="slide2"></div>
       <div id="slide"class="slide3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="A3L_Slogan">
      <div class="slogan_title">
        Hardcore Roleplay Community
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#slide {
position: fixed; 
}
```

to

```
#slide{
position: relative;
}
```

and the flow of the markup styling will be fixed. and you shouldn't use multiple ids `slide` with the same name in your markup it's very bad and will cause a hell of problems in the nearest future.

#### update:

As discussed in the comments, a better solution is to remove the duplicated divs and using img tags plus applying changes on js and css to avoid flickering and overflow-x. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eeymgo

Comment: Hi there, I just did that and ur solution works partially. It moves the text down, but when the slider changes the picture flickers below the text and back up. I tried removing the id slide from all slides but that doesn't work.

Comment: Removing the ids is not relative to the flickering but to a very bad practice that you should avoid doing it whether to use classes or use unique ids that's why it's called ids, the flickering happens because you animate using the display property. then showing and hiding, that's the cause. and mark the answer as a solution if it solved your problem ;).

Comment: Would there be an easy way of solving that?

Comment: The flickering due to me using that specific javascript

Comment: I did not try it myself but I would say add the slides as img tags and fade in as an img not a div of background-img.

Comment: I did try doing it via images, but that doesn't work. I've also tried changing up the Javascript code an CSS code, but it keeps flickering

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eeymgo wrapped the sliders in a slideshow div, add img instead of divs with background images. avoiding flickering by setting img position to absolute set top and left to 0 and overflow-x  of the body to hidden.

Comment: Best of luck, and I updated the answer to follow up with the comments.